# Polymer Properties order ... matters?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am finding very odd behavior of a Polymer element when defining properties of that element... specifically Arrays and Objects.

I have a dom-repeat template displaying this data Array, to give some context.

For example:

```
//.... Template definition
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'sample-element',
        properties:{
           user: {
              type:Object,
              notify: true,
           },
           data:{
              type: Array,
              value: function(){
                   return [
                    {'name':"Facebook", 'website': "http://www.facebook.com"},
                    {'name':"Twitter", 'website':"http://www.twitter.com"},
                    {'name':"Google",'website':"http://www.google.com"}];
              },
           }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This renders incorrectly, however if i switch the order of these properties, data is defined as an Array with 3 Objects when the template renders.

For example:

```
//.... Template definition
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'sample-element',
        properties:{
           data:{
              type: Array,
              value: function(){
                   return [
                    {'name':"Facebook", 'website': "http://www.facebook.com"},
                    {'name':"Twitter", 'website':"http://www.twitter.com"},
                    {'name':"Google",'website':"http://www.google.com"}];
              },
           },
           user: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true,
           },
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any clue why this works for defining the Object last? 
Console shows no errors in sample-element either...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default values the order indeed matters.

Maybe `user` tries to access the value of `data` which is not set yet.